# Converting SQL Server null date/time fields

Tags: sql, sql-server

Whenever the value is null for this query

```
SELECT ISNULL(someDateTime,'')
FROM  someTable
```

the result is

```
someDateTime  
------------
1900-01-01 00:00:00.000
```

I want it to be "No", so if I run this:

```
SELECT ISNULL(someDateTime,'No')
FROM  someTable
```

then there's this error:

> Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string.

How to do it?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: what do you want to show if the datetime is not null?

Comment: Do you mean SQL Server, or MySQL?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The result of the expression will need to be a single type.  If you want a character string (and you do, since 'No' is not a DateTime), you'll need to convert the datetime to such a string:

```
SELECT ISNULL(cast(someDatetime as varchar(20)), 'No') FROM someTable
```

As others have suggested, though, code like this smells bad, and you may want to pass the null to a client component and do the conversion there.

Comment: Thanks that did the trick, but to get the date into the mm/dd/yyyy format I did this: SELECT ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),someDateTime,101),'No')

Comment: Yeah, I didn't delve into correct converting.  I'm glad you got it working.

Answer (score 3):

`isnull()` is trying to convert the second argument to the datatype of the field you specify in the first argument.

If you are going to be returning a string you need to cast the `DateTime` field to a string type so that `isnull()` can work properly - see [Michael Petrotta's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201541/converting-mssql-null-date-time-fields/1201574#1201574) answer for a way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

You're still selecting a DateTime column, and so the result of that expression still needs to be a DateTime value rather than a string.  To suggest an appropriate work-around, we'll need to know more about what you're really trying to do with this data.

Answer (score 0):

You can't as such directly. It's easier to trap NULL in the client and change it to "no" there.

However, you could use a token value such as "17530101" which is a valid datetime, or CONVERT SomeDateTime first to varchar.

Otherwise, we need more info on why etc

Answer (score 0):

In your Update Stored Proc: Update your previous date value to a new Null value:

```
.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date_Value", Nothing).IsNullable = True
```